# How to write this Array in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays

My code in VBA Access is:

```
Dim K(10)
    for j=1 to 5
        K(j+1)= k(j)*2
    next
```

How I write this in SQL?

Comment: Look at this - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/faking-arrays-in-transact-sql/

Comment: What is it you actually want to achieve? Are you asking how to fill a table with values in SQL? Are you aware that VBA is a programming language whereas SQL is a language to query a database? They are made for very different purposes.

Comment: What is this code even supposed to do? Fill five of ten array entries with, er, nulls or zeros or something like that? (I have no experience with VBA, so I don't know what value is `k(1)`. Is it given some initial value with `DIM K(10)`?)

Comment: Thanks But i need K(1) to K(5) separately to do process on them without overwriting them. I want to allocate SQL fields to them not just  multiply them *2 .  5 times overwriting of @k does not solve the problem .K(i) is array to save some fields into and use them around the program .

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @k int = 10

Declare @j int = 1

While (@j<=5)
Begin
Set @k = @k * 2
print @k
Set @j = @j+1
End
```

Comment: Thanks But i need K(1) to K(5) to do process on it with 5 times print of @k

Comment: it will print @k five times, did you try to run this query?